# AS3 visible bounds of display object are offset inconsistently

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using this function, adapted from Plastic Sturgeon (http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/09/as3-get-visible-bounds-of-transparent-display-object/) to get the visible bounds of a display object.

```
public static function getVisibleBounds(source:DisplayObject):Rectangle
{
    var matrix:Matrix = source.transform.concatenatedMatrix;    
    var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1000, 1000,true,0x00000000);
    data.draw(source, matrix);
    var bounds:Rectangle = data.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF,0x000000,false);
    data.dispose();
    return bounds;
}
```

However, the bounds are offset from the object, depending on the stage size.  It works perfectly for the default stage size (550px×400px), but when either dimension is increased, it moves in the direction opposite to that dimension (when x is increased, it is offset from the object leftward, and when y is increased, it is offset from the object downward.) It doesn't do this consistently.  The offset(stage dimension) is non-linear, as it is 0 for a certain range of stage dimensions, then for stage dimensions greater than that range, it quickly rises with the stage dimension.  The offset is also different depending on what I changed the stage dimension from, e.g. if I go from 400px to 1000px in stages, testing movie in between, the boundaries are offset differently than if I go from 400px to 1000px all at once, or without testing movie at intermediate stages.  Sometimes the offset only changes with one dimension, and the other dimension doesn't do anything.  Also the published file is different from the test.  I tried putting the function in the same file as the display object, instead of in an external file, but that's still unreliable.  I wonder if there's some fix that could reliably give me the actual visible boundaries of the display object, regardless of the stage size and all this other stuff.

My computer runs Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit, and I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue that can be solved by setting some stage properties. First try setting the stage not to scale:

```
this.stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
```

Then set some alignment rules:

```
this.stage.align = "TL";
```

If that helps, it may be that your bitmap copying was running into some issues with scaling bugs.